# there are delays in calling setState if the list is large

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list on the screen which can be large, this list has a cursor that shows the selected item from the list and when the loop starts (there is a time pause in the loop: `Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {});` or change the cursor by touching the element, the cursor should quickly change its position, but when setState is called, the cursor changes its position very slowly with a delay of more than 100 milliseconds if the list is large. Is there a solution (example) to this problem?

```
void cycle() {
    var a = data.duration *
        (data.position.length);
    play();
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: (60000 / a).floor()), () {
      setState(() {
        cursor =
            operations.cursorMoveForward(cursor, data, _scrollController);
      });
      if (
          cursor.position == position.length - 1 || !onPlay) {
      } else {
        cycle();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: There are two solutions: batch the updates if the list is large and break it up into multiple tasks, or move the processing to an isolate.

Comment: Though there is a third option: change your approach to be more performant. It looks like you are making some sort of timeline seeker, perhaps for a A/V player or slideshow. If that's the case, I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: what if it is a local document, but not a text document, which the user himself creates and edits?

Comment: That question is far too vague for me to give a meaningful answer.